# MPAndroidChart vertical axis for 0 values

Tags: android, android-studio, bar-chart, mpandroidchart, yaxis

I am trying to populate a vertical bar chart with some values. I still want to keep as entry the values that are equal to 0. However, the chart looks suspicious when there is an existing entry that is equal to 0.

The first image shows how the chart looks if all the entries are not zero.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBBrn.jpg)
The second image shows how the chart looks if there is an entry equal to 0.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX0jb.jpg) (the chart does not exactly start from 0 on the vertical axis, it goes below)
The third image shows how the chart looks like if all entries are equal to zero.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTztj.jpg) (as you can see, the chart starts from -1 on the vertical axis)

Is there a way to make it look like in the first image, despite the 0 values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to achieve to start at zero even every value is 0. See in the code below, I commented everything:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BarChart barChart = findViewById(R.id.bar_chart);

        ArrayList<BarEntry> inventory = new ArrayList<>();
        inventory.add(new BarEntry(1f,0));
        inventory.add(new BarEntry(2f,10));
        inventory.add(new BarEntry(3f,20));
        inventory.add(new BarEntry(4f,30));
        inventory.add(new BarEntry(5f,40));
        
        //Colors & Textsize
        
        BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(inventory,"Inventory");
        barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
        barDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        barDataSet.setValueTextSize(16f);
        
        //Start at zero even all values are 0 for left YAxis.
        YAxis yAxis = barChart.getAxis(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
        yAxis.setStartAtZero(true);

        //Start at zero even all values are 0 for right YAxis.
        YAxis yAxis1 = barChart.getAxis(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
        yAxis1.setStartAtZero(true);

        //Define every space between the scales you want to.
        XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setGranularity(1.0f);
        xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);

        /*
        //Disables the right YAxis (Optional)
        YAxis rightYAxis = barChart.getAxisRight();
        rightYAxis.setEnabled(false);*/
        
        //Other Settings
        BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
        barChart.setData(barData);
        barChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        barChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
        barChart.animateX(500);

    }
}
```

If you want to customized further I suggest to take a look at the [documentation](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/).

**RESULT**

[image: Finish Bar Chart]

Comment: I still want to show on the graph because for my application, it is important if they are equal to 0. So i don’t want to filter them

Comment: So if everything is null you want to display the nulls but get rid of the -1? the negativ scale? I need a bit more information to help.

Comment: Do you still need help with that?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I am trying to do. I want to get rid of the -1 and I want the graph to start from 0 on the vertical axis, just like in the first image.

Comment: I updated my answer, please mark it as correct if that is what you wanted :)

Comment: It gets read of the negative scale, indeed. However, I want to keep the right Y axis( at least the line at the end of the chart) but the problem is that the values from the right Y axis do not correspond with the ones written on the left Y axis.

Comment: I fixed it in the code above. You need to define the right Chart setStartAtZero(true); also. Now both are beginning from 0. Cheers :)

Comment: I updated the picture for completeness as well.